# adding columnar values from a file in python

Tags: python

I have the following file:

`cat file.txt`

```
1/1 2/3
2/3 1/3
./2 1/1
./. 3/2
1/1 ./.
```

I would like to remove the dots and add the numbers from each column (delimited by a slashe and a space).

So far, I have:

```py
fp = open("file.txt","r")

for line in fp:
    cols = line.rstrip().split(" ")
    res = [int(cols[i][0]) for i in range(0,len(cols))].remove('.')
    print(sum(res))
```

I am trying to add the numbers before and after forward slash `'/'` in each column and output those delimited by `'/'`.

The expected output would be

```
4/7 7/9
```

Just one comment, the real file I'm working off of has more than 500 of these space delimited columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str` methods

**Ex:**

```
fp = """1/1 2/3
2/3 1/3
./2 1/1
./. 3/2
1/1 ./."""

c1, c2 = 0, 0
c3, c4 = 0, 0
for line in fp.splitlines():
    m, n = line.strip().split()
    m1, m2 = m.replace(".", "").split("/")
    n1, n2 = n.replace(".", "").split("/")
    if m1: c1 += int(m1)   #OR float(m1)
    if m2: c2 += int(m2)
    if n1: c3 += int(n1)
    if n2: c4 += int(n2)

print(f"{c1}/{c2} {c3}/{c4}")
```

**Output:**

```
4/7 7/9
```

---

Edit as per comment

```
result = [[0, 0] for i in range(2)] 
for line in fp.splitlines():
    row = line.strip().split()
    for idx, data in enumerate(row):
        m1, m2 = data.replace(".", "").split("/")
        if m1: result[idx][0] += int(m1)   #OR float(m1)
        if m2: result[idx][1] += int(m2)

print(result)

for m, n in result:
    print(f"{m}/{n}")
```

**Output:**

```
[[4, 7], [7, 9]]
4/7
7/9
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to avoid having to initialize c1,c2,c3,c4? The actual file has 500 columns

Comment: Updated snippet